# Return MYSQL Array from PHP to Javascript via a XHR Request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays, json

**PHP**

```
$table = $_REQUEST['table'];

$query  = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = $table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$i = 0;
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $arr[$i] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#verticalSelect").change(function() {
    var table = $("#verticalSelect option:selected").attr('value');

    $.post(PROCESSORFILE, {"task": "getTableDupeFields", "table": table}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }, "json");
});
```

I want take the array `$arr` from php and pass it to javascript where I can print its contents one by one. So far the code I have and variations of have returned errors, resource Id's and often just nothing at all.

How can this be done in the most trite way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, what's wrong:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $arr[$i] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
    $i++;
}
```

You're specifying `MYSQL_NUM`, which instructs `mysql_fetch_array()` to return a numeric array.  With that flag set, you'd access the first value as `$row[0]`.  To get an associative array and access the fields by name, you can either use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead, not pass any flag to `mysql_fetch_array()`, or pass it `MYSQL_ASSOC`.

Also, the `$i` variable you're using is unnecessary - you can append elements to an array without specifying an index, like so:

```
 $arr[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
```

Finally, your script is open to SQL injection when you insert a `$_REQUEST` variable directly into your sql.  At the very least, you should run `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the value before adding it to the SQL.

```
$table = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['table']);
```

Comment: It now works and returns a full array. I just sanitized it too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. `SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$table}`
2. `mysql_fetch_array($result)`
3. `$arr[] = $row['Field'];`
4. There is no need to use `$i` at all
5. `"json"` is not necessary
6. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use mysqli/PDO instead.
7. There is security issue in your script. Please escape `$table` to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$table` needs to be quoted in the query as its a string.

Your data is not sanitized and is open to sql injections

`mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)` does not return an associated array, specify `MYSQL_ASSOC` instead or use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead.

No need for `$i`, you can use `$arr[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];` to add an item to to the end of an array

> Use of the mysql_* extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

You can use `$("#verticalSelect").val()` to get the selected value select element.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wont us depreciated functions and take your advise. My code is now sanitized too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your using jquery so maybe use the getjson method. Also as you are just requesting data it is best to follow REST principles and use GET rather than POST unless of course your data is very large. This will help if you ever need caching and allows easy access to the resource.

```
$.getJSON("scripturl",function(data) {
$.each(data, function(i,item){
    console.log(item);
});
});
```